# Python/PyCharm doesn't recognize modules

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to run a [python project from github](https://github.com/johntrimble/foil-python) I follow some suggestions about the problem like change from Python 3 to Python 2, or check if the init.py is in each folder..., but I can't solve it.

This is the error I got

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Pulse/Desktop/foil-python-master/src/trimlogic/test/FamilyTreeTestCase.py", line 3, in 
>       from trimlogic.test.helper import FoilTestCase
>   ImportError: No module named trimlogic.test.helper

It doesn't matter if I run python2 or python 3, neither from console (CMD) or PyCharm

This is the structure of the project:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know specifically what your problem is, but can maybe help you find it.

Python does module imports by path. There is a magic environment variable called PYTHONPATH that tells it where to look for modules. So when you do `import trimlogic.test.helper` in a python file what happens is...

It looks at PYTHONPATH and gets a list of the directories in it.
It goes to the first one and looks to see if there is a `trimlogic.py` or a folder called `trimlogic` that includes the file `__init__.py`. If it finds a file `trimlogic.py` it will read it and look for a variable called `test`. If it is a folder, it will go into that folder and look for `test.py` or a folder called `test` with `__init__.py` in it. And so on. If it fails, it will check the rest of the directories in the PYTHONPATH variable the same way. Your command is failing because the `src` directory that contains the `trimlogic` folder is not on your PYTHONPATH.

There is a magic trick here. The current directory when you launch the python.exe is automatically added to the path. In a console, if you did `cd C:/Users/Pulse/Desktop/foil-python-master/src` and then tried running `python.exe trimlogic/test/FamilyTreeTestCase.py` your command would work as expected.

Further, Pycharm has some magic to help with this. First, if you right click the `src` directory and mark it as a `sources root` it will automatically run your python commands with that directory on the PYTHONPATH. You can also edit the run commands to change the working directory or the environment variables to be launched before executing commands.

Comment: Wow the right click and add as source root!!! That work!!! Thanks for the help!!!